# Relationship between input voltage and output voltage for an active filter

Tags: filter, transfer-function, active-filter

I'd like to know if I understood correctly the relationship between input voltage and output voltage for an active filter.
I study in French, so please understand if my glossary doesn't accord with English ones.
Say, [Av] is the coefficient of amplification(10^(Gain/20)). 
[Vi] is the input voltage and [Vo] is the output voltage.
Φ is the phase shift between [Vi] and [Vo].
So,
Vo = Av * Vi(ω*t+Φ)
Isn't it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is accurate for \$A_v\$ at a particular \$\omega\$. For example, take this graph:

[image]

This is the attenuation (attenuation = 1/gain) of a passive low pass filter. The gain is measured in decibels (dB), and, you are right, you convert from dB to Av with $$A_v = 10^{Gain/20} = 10^{-Attenuation/20}$$ So for low frequencies, the attenuation = 0, so \$A_v = 1\$. But, \$A_v\$, and \$\phi\$, change with frequency. For your equation to work, you need to turn \$V_i\$ into its frequency domain components, apply the equation to each component, and then integrate the components. So, for a square wave at 10 Hz, we know the wave will have decreasing harmonics at 30 Hz, 50 Hz, etc. To see what we would get out of the filter, we would apply the input harmonics, using the appropriate \$A_v\$ and \$\phi\$ for each frequency. So we would get:
$$ V_o=A_{v-10}*V_{i-10}*cos(10*t+\phi_{10}) + A_{v-30}*V_{i-30}cos(30*t+\phi_{30}) + ... $$
Where \$V_{i-10}\$ is the 10 Hz amplitude of the square wave, \$A_{v-10}, \phi_{10}\$ are the 10 Hz gain and phase shifts. If this were a more complicated signal, you would need to integrate it over all the frequencies.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you a lot. I am sorry for accepting the answer lately.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about an active filter, it is assumed that the input signal consists of many frequencies. Also the gain of the active filter will vary with frequency; otherwise it is not a filter.  The relationship you have is only valid for a single frequency (Note that Av will vary with frequency for a filter). At that frequency the filter will have a gain and a phase shift.  However the overall response of the filter will have a gain and phase that varies with frequency. It is usually described with two graphs: one for gain versus frequency and one for phase shift versus frequency.

Answer (score 0):

A filter is defined by the breakpoints in the design for bandpass, bandreject in dB and Hz, and the resulting slope is determined by the spec for the preceding values and also the order of the active filter.

One thing about filters is it impossible alter the amplitude slope without altering the slope of phase.  However there are many choices and Bessel Filter is the best for a flat group delay response.

Below is an example that shows amplitude, phase and group delay for a 1kHz Bessel low pass filter using the free TI design tool.
[image]